# How to access secret bundle content in oci goland sdk

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-go-sdk

I am using oci go sdk to access the secrets in oci. I get the SecretBundleResponse object but I want to extract the "Content" field which is present in resp.SecretBundleContent. There are no apis available on that object to extract it. Any help?
I am using https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/secretretrieval/20190301/SecretBundle/GetSecretBundle

```
    req := secrets.GetSecretBundleRequest{
        SecretId: common.String(secretID),
        Stage:    secrets.GetSecretBundleStageCurrent,
    }
    // Send the request using the service client
    resp, err := client.GetSecretBundle(context.Background(), req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Unable to get secrete bundle: ", err)
        return ""
    }
    log.Println("secret bundle resp Secret Bundle content", resp.SecretBundleContent)
    // secret bundle resp Secret Bundle content { Content=MyContent }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received response from Oracle internal slack channel with the solution. It seems I need to cast SecretBundleContent using Base64SecretBundleContentDetails type to access it's fields.

```
    var content string
    base64Details, ok := resp.SecretBundleContent.(secrets.Base64SecretBundleContentDetails)
    if ok {
        log.Println("base64 content details", *base64Details.Content)
        content = *base64Details.Content
    }
```